# Does it matter which vector(s) you remove from a linearly dependent set to achieve a linearly independent set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was wondering, if I'm given a set of say four vectors and that set is linearly dependent. And I'm asked to write one of the vectors as a linear combination of the other three. Would it matter which vector I chose to express in the other three?

Comment: If $v,w$ is a basis, then $v,w,w$ is a linearly dependent set, and you need to remove one of the $w$s, can't remove the $v$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters. For instance, if you have the vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ (in $k^3$, for some field $k$), you cannot express the third one (or the fourth one) as a linear combination of the other three.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters. Look at

$$
e_1 = \pmatrix{1 \\0}\\
e_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\1}\\
f_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\2}
$$
and suppose you have the set $\{e_1, e_2, f_2\}$. Then it's easy to write $f_2$ or $e_2$ as a combination of the others, but not $e_1$.

If you're only trying to *prove* the set is dependent, you can pick whichever one you like, but as in this example, if you pick the wrong one, you may not be able to use it to show the set is dependent, even if the set *is* dependent for other reasons.